# Typescript runtime module loading (with webpack) and dll-like late binding

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, requirejs, webpack-2

Suppose I have an ever growing set of different templates to be used with react. Each template `extends React.Component` and renders fancy border around its children.

I expect to generate such templates (with caching etc.) on the fly from some data known only at run-time.

At run-time I can compute the name of the module containing the template. I can map an URL to a server code to provide JavaScript source and expect the browser to be able to run it.

I imagine that I would isolate this piece of code in a simple method similar loading a *.DLL by name and calling its exported symbol. My guess below does not work.

```
private async templateLoader():Promise<React.ComponentType>{
    const templateModuleName:string = this.props.api.getTemplateName(this.props.user);
    return (await import(templateModuleName)) as React.ComponentType;
}
```

I can imagine JavaScript using require.js like so

```
var propsMappedFromStore=this.props;
//...
require(["api","user"],function(api,user){
  var templateModuleName = api.getTemplateName(user);
  require([templateModuleName],function(tt){
   propsMappedFromStore.updateTemplate(tt);
  })
})
```

But is it possible with Typescript and Webpack?

How would I require/import the module identified by expression?

Comment: "My guess below does not work." What didn't work. I would expect dynamic imports to work with webpack code splitting. See [this book](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/project/dynamic-import-expressions.html) for more info.

Comment: Code splitting does work. But the source of the "moment" module in the book is known at compile time, isn't it? I'm looking for a method where only interface is known but implementation evaluated at run-time. Perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for [import types](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2018/05/31/announcing-typescript-2-9/#import-types) which are available in TS 2.9

Answer (score 1):

While working on a React application I came across this problem. The application is split in multiple modules. Among those modules there is a set with specific properties. Those modules can not participate in webpack building process. They do not exist at design and build time. Instead, I know only shape of their export.

To use those modules browser must use a loader. `RequireJS` AMD loader is a good choice.

It took me quite time to figure out how to make WebPack to play nicely with async loading. The keyword here was **requirejs** instead of *require* or *import*.

Usage of requirejs eliminate any magic with webpack.config.js or any other magic. 
The code below should give you an idea. Using statement **requirejs(["locs/" + lang]…)** leads to a http request at **/{baseUrl}/locs/{lang}.js** which is handled by web server according it smartness.

```
import { getLanguage, IGreetingFormatStrings } from "./lociface";
import { defGeetings } from "./config";

function getGreetings(lang: string): Promise<IGreetingFormatStrings> {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        requirejs(["locs/" + lang]
            , (m) => { resolve(m.locGreetings as IGreetingFormatStrings); }
            , () => { resolve(defGeetings) }
        )
    });
}

export async function greeter(person: string): Promise<string> {
    const hours = new Date().getHours();
    const greetings = await getGreetings(getLanguage());
    if (hours > 6 && hours < 12) {
        return greetings.morning + person;
    }
    if (hours < 19) {
        return greetings.afternoon + person;
    }
    return greetings.night + person;
}
```

[image]